# Как заблокировать поле ввода не затемняя его. JAVA

Tags: java

Мне надо, чтобы текстовое поле в java (*JFormattedTextField*) **заблокировалось**, но **не затемнилось** как показано ниже.

Я знаю метод `.setEnabled(false)`, но он делает результат ниже.

[image: Петя]

Нужно чтобы было похоже на это, но **обязательно** заблокировано!

[image: Петя норм]

Comment: Перекрывать прозрачной областью?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте [JTextComponent.setEditable(false)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setEditable(boolean))

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает!